# R data.table select rows based on partial string match from character vector

Tags: r, data.table

I have a character vector and a data.tabe:

```
library(data.table)
pselection <- c("12345" , "2345", "12345678")
dt <- data.table("title"=c("First title", "Second Title", "Third Title", "Fourth Title"), 
                 "sha"=c("12345", "2345; 66543; 33423", "22222; 12345678;", "666662345; 444"))
```

Now I want to select all rows of the data.table which match the `sha` column partially based on the `;` seperator. So basically I want this output:

```
          title                sha
1:  First title              12345
2: Second Title 2345; 66543; 33423
3:  Third Title   22222; 12345678;
```

How would I do this?

I tried this:

```
selected <- dt[sha %in% pselection]
```

but it only selects exact matches and using the `%like%` expression is just for matching one expression not many. Concatenating to a regular expression (like `paste(pselection, collapse="|")`) is out of the question because my pselection is > 10.000.Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you need to use data.table or are you just looking for a solution for selecting partial string matches?

Comment: Would be nice to use data.table but any efficient enough solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution in mind using `lapply` and `tstrsplit`. There's probably more elegant but it does the job

```r
lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) {
  dt[i,'match' := any(trimws(tstrsplit(as.character(dt[i,'sha']),";")) %in% pselection)]
  })

dt[(match)]
          title                sha match
1:  First title              12345  TRUE
2: Second Title 2345; 66543; 33423  TRUE
3:  Third Title   22222; 12345678;  TRUE
```

The idea is to split every row of `sha` column (trim whitespace otherwise row 3 will not match) and check if any `sha` appears

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex`:

```
pselection <- paste0("\\b", pselection) # \b is boundary and includes ; and whitespace
dt[grepl(paste(pselection, collapse = "|"), sha)]

          title                sha
1:  First title              12345
2: Second Title 2345; 66543; 33423
3:  Third Title   22222; 12345678;
```